# How to put pause between ansible roles

Tags: ansible, syntax-error, wait, pause, ansible-role

Here is my playbook:

```
---
- hosts: "mms"
  user: wladmin

  roles:
    - { role: App1 }
    - { role: App2 }
    - { role: App3 }
    - { role: App4 }
```

I wish to put pause of 30 seconds between these ansible roles.

I tried the below but it give me syntax error:

```
  roles:
    - { role: App1 }
  pause:
    seconds: 30
    - { role: App2 }
  pause:
    seconds: 30
    - { role: App3 }
```

I also tried

```
  roles:
    - { role: App1 }
    - pause:
        seconds: 30
    - { role: App2 }
    - pause:
       seconds: 30
    - { role: App3 }
```

Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pause` isn't a role, so you can't include it in the `roles` section of your play. `pause` is a task. You have a couple of options:

### Use `import_role` tasks instead of the `roles` section

For example:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - import_role:
        name: App1
    - pause:
        seconds: 30
    - import_role:
        name: App2
    - pause:
        seconds: 30
    - import_role:
        name: App3
```

### Create a "pause" role

Create a `pause` role.  Put this in `roles/pause/tasks/main.yml`:

```
- name: pause
  pause:
    seconds: "{{ pause_seconds|default(30) }}"
```

And this in `roles/pause/meta/main.yml`:

```
allow_duplicates: true
```

Now you can write:

```
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - App1
    - pause
    - App2
    - pause
    - App3
```