# How to pause the playbook at the end of each host group?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I am performing rolling updates in several cluster. Each cluster is a group in inventory.

I want to pause the playbook when a cluster is done (a group of hosts) and not after every host.

```yaml
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

  - name: prompt 1
    pause: 
      prompt: prompt1
    run_once: true

  - name: prompt 1
    pause:
      prompt: prompt2
    run_once: true

- hosts: "{{ target }}"
  gather_facts: no
  serial: 1
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  ignore_unreachable: true

  roles:
    - app
```

I would like to pause the playbook after one host group before the next host group begin.

For eg, If I have the group called `eu_app`, `us_app`, then after deploying all hosts in group `eu_app`, playbook has to wait for 15 minutes to deploy for next group `us_app`.

I tried using `loop_control` with `group_names` but it is pausing the playbook even for child groups present for the parent group. Pause should happen only for parent group.

Answer (score 0):

> *I want to pause the playbook when a cluster is done (a group of hosts) ... I would like to pause the playbook after one host group before the next host group begin.*

According the documentation and example under [Playbook execution](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_intro.html#playbook-execution), a  minimal example with `hosts` like

```ini
[eu_app]
eu1.example.com
eu2.example.com
eu3.example.com

[us_app]
us1.example.com
us2.example.com
us3.example.com
```

```bash
ansible-inventory -i hosts --graph
@all:
  |--@eu_app:
  |  |--eu1.example.com
  |  |--eu2.example.com
  |  |--eu3.example.com
  |--@us_app:
  |  |--us1.example.com
  |  |--us2.example.com
  |  |--us3.example.com
  |--@ungrouped:
```

and playbook like

```yaml
---
- hosts: eu_app
  become: false
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:

  - name: Show Facts
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    when: item == inventory_hostname
    loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"

  - name: Make sure service has time to start or stop
    pause:
      seconds: 900 # 15 min
    when: not ansible_check_mode

- hosts: us_app
  become: false
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:

  - name: Show Facts
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    when: item == inventory_hostname
    loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
```

will result into the requested execution.

An other approach is shown under [How to put `pause` between Ansible roles?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68795203/6771046)